# Lentidão ao fazer leitura de uma string muito grande

Tags: javascript, java

Estou perdendo muita a performace ao fazer um `decodeBase64`, quando tenho um arquivo muito grande tipo 30MB, demora muito para ler os dados recebido do front.

Existe alguma forma de melhorar a leitura desse arquivo que está em fileBase64?

No front o arquivo está assim:

```
reader.onload = function (readerEvt) {
        var anexosTemp = [];
        $scope.$apply(function () {
           var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
           var fileBase64 = btoa(binaryString);

           anexoVO = {
              dados: fileBase64,
              nome: vm.anexo.arquivo.name,
              descricao: vm.anexo.descricao,
              tamanho: vm.anexo.arquivo.size,
              tipo: vm.anexo.arquivo.type,
           };

           anexosTemp.push(anexoVO);
           vm.anexo = null;

        });

        var url = null;

        if ($location.host() === "localhost") {
           url = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        } else {
           url ="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        }

        var configHttp = {
           transformRequest: angular.identity,
           headers: {
              'Content-Type': undefined
           }
        };

        var formulario = new FormData();
        vm.solicitacao.anexos = anexosTemp;
        formulario.append("file", JSON.stringify(vm.solicitacao));

        $http.post(url, formulario, configHttp)
```

No Java faço isso:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public CSResponse adicionarArquivo(String strSolicitacao){
String[] str = strSolicitacao.split("file\"");
    String[] str2 = str[1].trim().split("------");
    String solJson = str2[0].trim();
    Gson g = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new 
    GsonUTCDateAdapter()).create();
    Sol sol = g.fromJson(solJson, Sol.class);
}
```

Só que esse processo na leitura do meu atributo `dados` demora muito quando ele está lendo. Como faço para melhorar o desempenho na leitura dessa string `gigante` que vem através do meu js e esse fazer com esse JSON ser mais rápido convertido?

Comment: porque você usa btoa pra converter ele pra base64 no js se no java você volta ele pra byte array?

Comment: Cara tinha feito a pergunta errada, reformulei a minha pergunta, o problema é quando converto para JSON.